# Cache Attached - How to use in Customer and BAccount Table on User Defined fields

Tags: acumatica

I added a new user defined field (additional employee) in BAccount Table which I want to show Sales Person for the Customer and Buyer for the Vendor !

I added a Cache Attached event in Customer Maint Extension Graph and also in the VendorMaint Extension Graph.

I cannot enter PXDBInt in the Code there ! Gives Error !

Without PXDBInt, if I use Customer_UsrPMEmployee_CacheAttached it publishes but does not update the field when I Save.

If I use - BAccount_UsrPMEmployee_CacheAttached It gives error in Customer !

Can anybody say the exact way to handle this ?

The Code

[PXDBEmployeeSelector]
[PXUIField("Sales")]

Comment: Where is PXDBEmployeeSelector coming from? I'm not seeing it in recent version of Acumatica product. If it's declaring a PXDB attribute in there than you shouldn't decorate it with PXDBInt.

Comment: I am using  6.10.1219. And it works. Nevertheless, I had an urgency so I created two separate fields - Sales Person and Buyer field and made them visible and accepted in two separate forms and proceeded forward. Thanks for the response.